# how to include other javascript files in content js file of chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, requirejs

I have made a chrome extension ! it gives css and xpath on click at any point on the web page. I have include my js files for calculating xpath and css in content scripts of chrome extension. Is there any way by which i can include only on js file in content script and import all other js files inside that one js file ?

I tried the require and export which i got when i searched but its not working.

```
var xPath = {};
xPath.get_xpath=function(ele)
{
}
export xpath = xpath;
```

and i tried to import it using require like this :

```
var calculate = require("xpath");
```

but its showing error export not defined.

Comment: Why are you trying to only include one ("on"?) js file?  What's wrong with just including all of your js files?

Comment: I am including all now ! i was just trying to see if there is other way or not @Teepeemm

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

```
var xPath = {};
xPath.get_xpath = function(ele) {
}
module.exports = xPath;
```

Note that Chrome doesn't support JS modules, so you need to use [browserify](http://browserify.org/) builder.

As an example, check my open source extension: [Clipboardy](https://github.com/panzerdp/clipboardy).

Comment: it is showing error " module is not defined "
May you please guide me through if need to add any external file first anywhere in my manifest file ?@Dmitri

Comment: @Ram You need to use a builder like `browserify` to have access to `require()` and modular system.

Comment: you mean i need to install this first ? is there any other way to achieve this so that it works in my chrome extension. @Dmitri

Comment: Nope, you need a builder.

Comment: can you explain me a bit how to use browserify to get access to require in my extension ? i saw your extension link but could not understand much as i am new to this ! @Dmitri